# How to transform my code for speed (for loop)

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

**UPDATE: I reduced my code to the pivotal elements to shorten it**

The function_impact_calc is very slow (26 secs for 100000 records dataframe). I think the main reason is the **for loop** (maybe apply or map will help?). Below I simulate the data, write impact_calc function and record run time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

###########################################################
# Start Simulate Data
###########################################################


BuySell <- function(m = 40, s = 4) {
  S <- pmax(round(rnorm(10, m, s), 2), 0)
  S.sorted <- sort(S)
  data.frame(buy = rev(head(S.sorted, 5)), sell = tail(S.sorted, 5))
}

number_sates <- 10000

lst <- replicate(number_sates, BuySell(), simplify = FALSE)

# assemble prices data frame

prices <- as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(lst))
prices$state_id <- rep(1:number_sates, each = 5)
prices$level <- rep(1:5, times = number_sates)

prices$quantities <- round(runif(number_sates * 5, 100000, 1000000), 0)
# reshape to long format
prices_long <- reshape2::melt(prices,
  id.vars = c("state_id", "quantities", "level"),
  value.name = "price"
) %>%
  rename("side" = "variable") %>%
  setDT()

###########################################################
# End  Simulate Data
###########################################################
```

Here is the function impact_calc which is very slow.

```
##########################################################
# function to optimize

impact_calc <- function(data, required_quantity) {
  
  # get best buy and sell
  
   best_buy <- data[, ,.SDcols = c("price", "side", "level")][side == "buy" & level == 1][1, "price"][[1]]

  best_sell <- data[, ,.SDcols = c("price", "side", "level")][side == "sell" & level == 1][1, "price"][[1]]
  
  # calculate mid
  
  mid <- 0.5 * (best_buy + best_sell)
  
 
    # buys
   
    remaining_qty <- required_quantity
    impact <- 0
    
     data_buy <- data[, ,][side == "buy"]
    
    
    levels <- data_buy[, ,][side == "buy"][, level]
    
    
    
    # i think this for loop is slow!
    
    for (level in levels) {
      price_difference <- mid - data_buy$price[level]
      if (data_buy$quantities[level] >= remaining_qty) {
        impact <- impact + remaining_qty * price_difference
        remaining_qty <- 0
        
        break
      } else {
        impact <- impact + data_buy$quantities[level] * price_difference
        remaining_qty <- remaining_qty - data_buy$quantities[level]
      }
    }
    
    rel_impact <- impact / required_quantity / mid
 
  
  
  return_list <- list("relative_impact" = rel_impact)
}
```

The results with run time:

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
impact_buys <- prices_long[, impact_calc(.SD, 600000), by = .(state_id)]
end_time <- Sys.time()

end_time - start_time
# for 100000 data frame it takes
#Time difference of 26.54057 secs
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Too long; didn't read. One tip however is not using `reshape2` nor `dplyr`, but the equivalent functions in `data.table`.

Comment: @sindri_baldur - Thanks for your comment! I reduced my code to make it much shorter. reshape2 I am using only to simulate data.frame to make my problem reproducible. Simulate data part should not be optimized. Only the function impact_calc. And I suppose that the for loop is the bottleneck.

Comment: @sindri_baldur - In addition, I changed best_buy and best_sell from dplyr filtering to data.table and it reduced the run time by 1/3rd! But still its taking 12 seconds on this small dataset

Comment: Also changed all remaining dplyr elements in impact_calc to data.table - this helps. Now, I increased the data.frame to 100K records - it takes 26 secs (for loop is slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's suspicion is correct: By replacing the for loop by vector operations we can speed up the calculation by a factor of over 100:

```
required_quantity <- 600000
setDT(prices)
library(bench)
mark(
  orig = prices_long[, impact_calc(.SD, required_quantity), by = .(state_id)],
  mod1 = prices_long[, impact_calc2(.SD, required_quantity), by = .(state_id)],
  vec_w = prices[, {
    mid <- 0.5 * (buy[1L] + sell[1L])
    tmp <- cumsum(quantities) - required_quantity
    list(relative_impact = 
           sum(pmin(quantities, pmax(0, quantities - tmp)) * (mid - buy)) / 
           required_quantity / mid)
  }, by = .(state_id)],
  min_time = 1.0
)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 13
>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory    time  gc    
>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>    <lis> <list>
> 1 orig          28.1s    28.1s    0.0356    2.21GB     1.39     1    39      28.1s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 2 mod1          13.1s    13.1s    0.0762  658.42MB     1.45     1    19     13.12s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 3 vec_w       175.1ms  196.9ms    5.19    440.19KB     2.59     6     3      1.16s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> ```

In addition to the speed up, the vectorized version `vec_w` allocates remarkably less memory (about 5000 times).

Note that the vectorized version `vec_w` is using the original `prices` dataset in wide format. So, there is no need to reshape the data from wide to long format.

The second benchmark case `mod1` is a version of `impact_calc()` where the code *outside* of the for loop code has been modified to make better use of the `data.table` syntax. These minor modifications alone account for a speed-up by a factor of 2.

The results are identical which is checked by `mark()`.

#### Explanation of `vec_w`

If I understand correctly, the OP considers quantities in the given `level` order until `required_quantity` is reached. The last level is considered only partiallly to the extent which is required to meet `required_quantity` exactly.

In a vectorised version this can be achieved by nested `ifelse()` as shown in this example:

```
library(data.table)
r <- 5
dt <- data.table(q = 1:4)
dt[, csq := cumsum(q)]
dt[, tmp := csq - r]
dt[, aq := ifelse(tmp < 0, q, ifelse(q - tmp > 0, q - tmp, 0))][]
```

> ```
>    q csq tmp  aq
> 1: 1   1  -4   1
> 2: 2   3  -2   2
> 3: 3   6   1   2
> 4: 4  10   5   0
> ```

The temporary variable `tmp` holds the difference between the cumulated sum of quantities `q` and the required quantity `r`.

The first `ifelse()` tests if the cumulated sum of quantities `q` is below the required quantity `r`. If so then use `q` without deduction. If not then use the part of `q` which is required to fill up the cumulated sum of actual quantities `aq1` to meet the required quantity `r`.

The second `ifelse()` ensures that the quantity `q` minus deduction is positive (which is the case for the incomplete level) or zero (for the remaining levels below).

The actual quantities `aq = c(1, 2, 2, 0)` derived by the previous steps do sum up to the requested quantity `r = 5`.

---

Now, the `ifelse()` constructs can be replaced by `pmin()` and `pmax()`:

```
dt[, aq := pmin(q, pmax(q - tmp, 0))]
```

I have verified in a separate benchmark (not posted here) that the `pmin()`/`pmax()` approach is slightly faster than the nested `ifelse()`.

#### Explanation of `mod1`

In function `impact_calc()` some code lines can be modified to make use of the `data.table` syntax.

Thus,

```
best_buy <- data[, .SD,.SDcols = c("price", "side", "level")][side == "buy" & level == 1][1, "price"][[1]]
best_sell <- data[, .SD,.SDcols = c("price", "side", "level")][side == "sell" & level == 1][1, "price"][[1]]
```

become

```
best_buy <- data[side == "buy" & level == 1, first(price)]
best_sell <- data[side == "sell" & level == 1, first(price)]
```

and

```
data_buy <- data[, ,][side == "buy"]
levels <- data_buy[, ,][side == "buy"][, level]
```

become

```
data_buy <- data[side == "buy"]
levels <- data[side == "buy", level]
```

I was quite surprised to learn that these modifications *outside* of the for loop already gained a substantial speed increase.

Comment: Thank you very much, Uwe! Very valuable answer! That's the best way how to improve my skills!